# Best way to start with Bitcoin today

Tags: buy-bitcoins, business, earnings, job

Question for those with considerable experience in bitcoin: 
If you would start with Bitcoin today what would be your primary way for:

- Short-term (in a month) way of obtaining bitcoins
- Medium-term (in about 6 months) way of obtaining bitcoins
- Long-term (more than 12 months) way of obtaining bitcoins

Please mention what resources and knowledge would you need for each these.

Answer (score 0):

this is not an experts judgement, so here are my two cents to this more or less "unprecise" question - you didn't say, what you want to do with bitcoin (use case):

*short term: try a mobile (SPV) wallet or the bitcoin-QT, play some faucets, and start understanding the wording around bitcoin. Very little ressources required, only little knowledge required (reading some forums and bitcoin.org, of course).

*mid term: buy your bitcoins on an exchange or other provider (here in Switzerland we have the railway service - every of their terminals allows you to buy bitcoins). Get prepared to understand the security model of bitcoin - you are your own bank! You don't need special skills, just a good financial understanding.

*long term: develop in any language a trx analyzer or similiar, to understand the logic (and pitfalls) of the environment. This requires programming skills, and a developper machine...